# Can't join Azure DC VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, entra-id, entra-domain-services

I have my on-premise computer which is connected to an Azure Virtual Network with a VPN Gateway.

I can ping with the private IP an Azure VM which is a Domain Controller, and even access to its file share.

But I can't join my W10 to the domain.(DNS Name doesn't exist).

The DNS IP of my W10 :

- 8.8.8.8
- 10.0.1.5 (Azure VM DC)

Regards.

Comment: Your DC should be first in the DNS list

Comment: What Sam said is correct.